# Deploying Flask app in Google App Engine resulting in "gunicorn: error: No application module specified."

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

Smacking my head against a desk trying to get this one to work. I'm trying to deploy a simple Flask app on gunicorn through Google App Engine. When visiting the app, I'm getting Error 500, with "gunicorn: error: No application module specified." in the logs.

My layout is roughly:

```
Main_Directory/
|-MyApp/
|   |-__init__.py <- Containing majority of code
|   |-templates/
|   |-static/
|-app.yaml
|-main.py 
|-requirements.txt
```

`main.py` simply imports the app from `MyApp` and instantiates a new instance called "app".

`requirements.txt` has all dependencies, including gunicorn.

app.yaml is exactly as follows:

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F1
default_expiration: "4d 12h"
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 1

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "bucket_name"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

I tried creating another app.yaml within the `MyApp` folder and adding service: "default" but that didn't help. I'm pretty much out of ideas here. I'm fairly certain the issue is because the main app code is defined in `MyApp`, rather than directly under the `Main_directory`. I appreciate the easy solution would be to bring everything from the `MyApp` folder up a level but I'm hesitating to do this as it will mess with my Git. I thought creating main.py and directly instantiating `MyApp/__init__.py` would do the trick, but doesn't quite seem to.

Any and all ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, after reaching my limit and raising a question, I found an answer...

I removed the entrypoint from `app.yaml` and removed gunicorn from `requirements.txt`. On redeploying the app, it now works.

I don't feel like this is a fix, so much as a workaround. I'm still not sure why it didn't work before. There must be better solutions which maintain gunicorn as a requirement. I expect it was the yaml that was wrong.

Comment: Yes, you had an error in the entrypoint in your app.yaml file.  Removing it reverts to the default entrypoint which works find in most cases.

Comment: Same problem for me. No solution: Whenever I try to specify the entrypoint with flask and python 3, I get the same error. Only when I remove entrypoint completely and name my first file main.py, then it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use gunicorn as your HTTP server, you need to tell it where your WSGI app is located. This is likely an `app` variable in your `main.py` file, so you can use:

```yaml
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 1 main:app
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause this error is if the `gunicorn.conf.py` file is missing.